# Paypal Subscription

Tags: paypal-subscriptions, omnipay

I have used  omnipay before in a laravel project to process payments but i want be able to manage paypal subscriptions. can  omnipay do this? If not can someone point me in the right direction.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is not documented very well but the omnipay [rest gateway](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal/blob/master/src/RestGateway.php) exposes the subscription methods (even when it's own documentation says it doesn't). 
Omnipay does not support it in a standard structure (see [this thread](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay/issues/33#issuecomment-98167661)) but it is encouraging people to implement them within gateways in the hope of being able to see the common structure and standardise it eventually.

If you look carefully you will find a few drivers support subscriptions (braintree, paypal and stripe all spring to mind) but they are all custom.

Answer (score 0):

No. As per the [readme](https://packagist.org/packages/omnipay/paypal).

> Omnipay does not cover recurring payments or billing agreements, and so those features are not included in this package. Extensions to this gateway are always welcome.